# A class to store the number of seconds since midnight

Tags: java, datetime

The purpose of this code is to to implement the time as the number of seconds since midnight. The class  should have one data field (an int  with the number of seconds since midnight) instead of three. The Driver class will test the Time2 class . This program should ask the user to input the number of hours, minutes, and seconds past midnight, creating a Time2 object  and using the mutator methods . The program  should then use the toString() method  to print out the time.

I am unsure if I could put `throw new IllegalArgumentException` into a single statement if I need 3. But I have the code working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Time2 time = new Time2();

    System.out.print("Enter hours:");
    int hours = input.nextInt();                                
    System.out.print("Enter minutes:"); 
    int minutes = input.nextInt();                              
    System.out.print("Enter seconds:"); 
    int seconds = input.nextInt();

    time.setHour(hours);
    time.setMinute(minutes);
    time.setSecond(seconds);    
    time.toString();
}

public static class  Time2 {

private  int  hour; 
private  int  minute;
private  int  second;   

public Time2() {this(0, 0, 0);}
public Time2(int  hour) {this(hour, 0, 0);}
public Time2(int  hour, int  minute) {this(hour, minute, 0);}

public Time2(int  hour, int  minute, int  second) {
    if(hour<0||hour>=24)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour must be 0-23");
    if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minute must be 0-59");
    if (second < 0 || second >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("second must be 0-59");
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
}

public Time2(Time2 time) {this(time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond());}

public void setTime(int  hour, int  minute, int  second) {
    if (hour<0||hour>=24)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour must be 0-23");
    if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minute must be 0-59");
    if (second < 0 || second >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("second must be 0-59");
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
}

public void setHour(int  hour) {
    if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour must be 0-23");
    this.hour = hour;
}

public void setMinute(int  minute) {
    if (minute < 0 && minute >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minute must be 0-59");
    this.minute = minute;
}

public void setSecond(int  second) {
    if (second <= 0 || second > 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("second must be 0-59");
    this.second = second;
}

public int  getHour() {return hour;}
public int  getMinute() {return minute;}
public int  getSecond() {return second;}

public String  toUniversalString() {
    return String .format( "%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(), getSecond());
}

public String  toString() {
    return String .format("%d:%02d:%02d %s",
                          ((getHour() == 0 || getHour() == 12) ? 12 : getHour() % 12), getMinute(),
                          getSecond(), (getHour() < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));
}
}
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  The question states that there should only be one data field instead of three.   But the code has three data fields.  So the code does not meet the stated requirements.  Isn't that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your validation is too strict, as a minute can sometimes have 61 seconds. Limiting it to 60 seconds is what causes [computer crashes during leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second#Examples_of_problems_associated_with_the_leap_second).

To avoid code duplication, the `Time(hour, minute, second)` constructor should just do:

```
public Time(int hour, int minute, int second) {
    this.setHour(hour);
    this.setMinute(minute);
    this.setSecond(second);
}
```

Your spacing is a bit weird here:

> ```
> return String .format( "%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(), getSecond());
> ```

It would be more conventional to write:

```
return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(), getSecond());
```

Comment: Im not sure how to implement that, can u further explain please?